# How to implement menu navigation from created table in jQuery

Tags: jquery, menu

I'm new to jQuery/Javascript.  I have page that creates a table object after getting XML data from the website.  I'd like to offer a navigation menu when the user clicks or hovers over a table row.  The menu should be clickable to create additional page elements.

How should I go about this?

So far attempted hover methods don't seem to find any row.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather difficult question to answer without seeing the generated table and not knowing what you want to do with said table. However:

```
            $("#tableid td").click(function(){
                // Do something here
            });
```

Should pretty much handle what you need.

Comment: The table starts like this:    txt = "<table border='1' id=\"myid\">" followed by some rows and cells.  How do I determine which row was clicked?

Comment: Gerry, it depends on what you want to know about the row. If you just want to know its order in the whole table, you can do this: `$("#myid tr").click(function(){ $(this).index(); });` If you're trying to tie it to a specific record from the data, you could create the table with `<td id="r1">` and then do `$("#myid tr").click(function(){ $(this).attr("id").strpos(1); });`